# adding data from excel to existing table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel

I have an existing table on MySQL with 7 fields - 4 are integer(one acting as primary key and auto incremete) and  3 text. This table already has data.

I am collecting new data in Excel and wish to bulk-add the data to the Mysql table. Some of the cells in Excel will be blank and need to show as null in MySQL and the primary key won't be part of excel, I let MYSQL auto add it. Previously I was manually adding each record through PHPmyadmin but it is far too time consuming (I have 1000's of records to add).

How do I go about this in terms of setting the Excel sheet in the right way and making sure I add to the exsisting data instead of replacing it? I have heard CSV files are the way? I use PHPmyadmin if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to import the data to MySQL? Or do you want to write a piece of VBA code that reads the data you enter and adds it to your MySQL database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append data to a MySQL table, I would use .csv files to do it.

In MySQL:

```
load data local infile 'yourFile'
into table yourTable (field1, field2, field3)
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'  -- On windows you may need to use `\r\n'
ignore 1 lines;           -- Ignore the header line
```

Check the reference manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I managed to get it to work with PHPmyadmin, following your method

Comment: Quick question - The rows that were blank do not say 'null', what is the easiest way either with MySQL or Excel to ensure the empty records are marked as null and not just blank? thanks